# Setting log level in Spring Boot apps?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, yaml

I am using the following log setting in my `application.yml`, but I am not sure if it is a proper configuration.

```
logging:
  pattern:
    console: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
    file: "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"
  level:
    org.springframework: error
    org.hibernate: error
    com.company: debug
```

Regarding to `file` and `level` sections, how should I set my application for dev and prod environments?

Also I am not sure if I should use a level for my base package as `com.company`. Is there any level to be added or removed in the level section?

Comment: For different environments you can create multiple profiles to mange diff logging levels, just like any other property.

Comment: Yes, I am asking that. What would be a good practies for these environments? (level of the logs)

Comment: And also what about deleting log file periodically?